# Connotations of "off the reservation"

Tags: etymology, idioms

I just used the phrase *"to go off the reservation"* -- in the context of the workplace, to go in a direction that management might not approve of -- and realized how strange it is.  What are the (historical and present-day) connotations of that term?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Wiktionary entry for "off the reservation"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_off_the_reservation) three definitions for the expression:

1. (literally) To leave a reservation to which one was restricted.
2. (US, politics) To break with one's party or group, usually temporarily.
3. (by extension) To engage in disruptive activity outside normal bounds.

The second definition also finds an entry in [Safire's Political Dictionary](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=c4UoX6-Sv1AC&pg=PA489) which additionally also adds a note on its origin:

> The metaphor is rooted in traders' lingo, referring to Indian reservations in the days when unscrupulous whites would trade "[firewater](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/firewater)" for goods, and *off the reservation* was a lonely and dangerous place for an aboriginal American to be.

Comment: Thanks.  I was partly wondering if the phrase was offensive -- not really, it seems.

Comment: @dbaseman: I think maybe you've not taken those connotations fully on board. In most contexts, if you told someone that they were *off [the] reservation*, that would be ***extremely offensive***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was thinking more of referring to oneself going off the reservation, rather than accusing someone else of doing it.  But you're right, that would be begging for an indignant retort and/or lawsuit in some contexts.

Comment: @dbaseman: Ah right. Yeah - I can't see any danger of giving offence if you use the term *of yourself*. Except if there are any native Indians involved in the conversation, in which case you might be sailing a bit close to the wind.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As a sailor, _I_ take offence to that last comment. :)

Comment: You can use off the reservation and it is not offensive in any context if used as definition 3. Simply means to go your own way or behave out of bounds. Saying someone is out of bounds or 'calling someone out' generally will cause offense no matter what terminology is used. If someone takes offense to being told they're off the reservation the 99% likelihood is they're offended by being told their not making the cut regardless of how badly they are acting.

Comment: I'm surprised at Safire's finding the metaphor to be "rooted in traders' lingo." My impression was that it referred to abandoning the reservation, as Geronimo (among other Native American leaders) did, in order to resume hostilities with U.S. settlers and their protectors. In the great (and unflinching) film _Ulzana's Raid_ (1972), I believe the term used is "jumping the reservation"—an act that Burt Lancaster's character points out was prompted at least as much by the lousy supplies that traders brought to the reservation as to any spontaneous restlessness on the Native Americans' part.

Comment: Since telling someone they are off the reservation is really saying "you're acting like a native American person who has left the confines of their prison ghetto and is acting like a savage among the civilized" then yes I'd say it is offensive and is akin to comparing someone to be "n bomb rich"

Answer (score 0):

For an Indian to go off the reservation is to engage in disruptive activity outside normal bounds, so yes, it is offensive. Please do not use it. Reservations were prisons set up for people who were pushed off their own land. They are place of drunken misery and poverty.